# Editing a WordPress theme for Font Awesome video icon overlay

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am using a WordPress theme called Madd Magazine. I primarily chose this theme because it places a Font Awesome icon overlay on post thumbnails that contain video content.

My dilemma is that I want to add this same functionality to the post thumbnails on the left and right-hand side as well. I have attached a screenshot of the icon overlay that is created for the 2 posts directly below the main slider. I believe the code that adds those 2 thumbnails below the slider is located in the [content-archive.php](http://www.webfxonline.com/downloads/content-archive.txt) file (attached) and the [style.css](http://www.webfxonline.com/downloads/style.css) (attached).

The 2 files that create the small thumbnails on the left and right-hand sides are [sidebar.php](http://www.webfxonline.com/downloads/sidebar.txt) and [sidebar-right.php](http://www.webfxonline.com/downloads/sidebar-right.txt) (attached). Can somebody please help me to get that same image overlay functionality on the left and right hand posts that contain video content?
The image below is done in Photoshop but this is a representation of what I want to achieve thru css/html on the smaller thumbnails.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvJKt.png)

```html
here is the code that creates those play button overlays:

....            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
....                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php ....the_title_attribute(); ?>">
....                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('madd-magazine-blog-post'); ?....>
....                    <?php if ( has_post_format( 'video' )) : ?>
....                        <span class="video-label"></span>
....                    <?php endif; ?>
```

[image]

Comment: Have a look at the .video-label:before pseudo element styling in the css file. Is that what you are after?

Comment: I know that from line 1089 thru 1115 in my style.css defines the size and position, etc for the Font Awesome "play button" I'm using.  I'm good with those parameters, I just want to  apply those same settings to the widget on the right and left to display over the smaller blog post thumbnails too.

Comment: I think you need to find this function: dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-widget2') and then we can see where to add the video class stuff. Is your site live anywhere so I could look?

Comment: Yes here ya' go- http://www.webfxonline.com/

Comment: here is the code for the "right" sidebar widget

Comment: http://www.webfxonline.com/downloads/sidebar-right.txt

Comment: I've tried inserting this code into my sidebar-right.php to duplicate the existing function but no luck....     <?php if ( has_post_format( 'video' )) : ?>
      <span class="video-label"></span>

Comment: here is my "test" site and as you can see all of the images beneath the main slider with video content place the "font Awesome" play button over the top of the thumbnails of posts that have video content.  https://www.webfxonline.com/test/

Comment: You need to find the code for function dynamic sidebar.

Comment: I believe that the code for the Dynamic Sidebar is generated here: http://www.webfxonline.com/downloads/sidebar-right.txt

Comment: I've tried inserting this code into my sidebar-right.php http://www.webfxonline.com/downloads/sidebar-right.txt to duplicate the existing function but no luck.... <?php if ( has_post_format( 'video' )) : ?> <span class="video-label"></span>

Comment: Where are you inserting it, after the img?

Comment: this is the sidebar-right.php file that I have simply named sidebar-right.txt so that you could see how it is structured.  The "real" sidebar-right.php file is still located in the appropriate folder.

Comment: like this: http://www.webfxonline.com/downloads/sidebar-right.txt

Comment: getting this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting elseif (T_ELSEIF) or else (T_ELSE) or endif (T_ENDIF) in